# Why homgraphy matrix doesn't work for any point in the image?

Tags: opencv, homography

I'm trying to find homography between two images. If I calculate homography based on only corresponding points on the ground then the transformation works well only for the points on the ground.
If I calculate homography based on only corresponding points on not on the ground then the transformation works well only for the points on that level.

How do I get homography that will work for any point on the image? Is it even possible ?

Comment: it is not possible, since such a homography can only describe the transformation between two planes.

Comment: what should I do to so I'll be able to do between several planes?

Comment: you can conpute different homographies for different planes or, if you know certain pixels in your image should have some fixed height position relative to the ground plane, you can trace a ray from camera center through pixel and stop at that height

Comment: I thought about different homos for different planes, but it's not practical in my case.

Comment: In general, if homography describes transformation between planar surfaces, what's called the transformation between non-planar ones?

Comment: in 3D space you can use 4x4 linear transformations (for non-deformable objects). In 3D-to-2D it is (e.g. perspective) projection (e.g. following the ray from the object to the projection center) to a plane (e.g. the image plane of the camera).

Comment: so what you need to do is: reconstruct the 3D scene from your first image, compute the camera position of the 2nd image, relative to the first image, project the 3D scene to the second camera. Nothing of this is an easy problem and reconstructing a single scene from a single camera image is impossible without assumptions or depth information.

Comment: sorry, missed one point. Please have a look at epipolar geometry, which should be what you are looking for and maybe there are fine solutions nowadays.

Comment: @Micka, if I have extrinsic and intrinsic matrices of both cameras, how can I achive this if I don't have heights of the players?

Comment: have a look at epipolar geometry. I don't have enough knowledge there  myself, sorry.